# Package tikz Error when writing some text in verbatim

Tags: tikz-pgf, verbatim

I got from texlive on windows 8.1 an error when I wrote some text in verbatim.

The error was:

```
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmtt.fd)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/ts1lmtt.fd)

! Package tikz Error: Sorry, some package has redefined the meaning of the math
-mode dollar sign. This is incompatible with tikz and its calc library and migh
t cause unrecoverable errors.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

But if I remove the verbatim mode the tex file can be compiled with no error.

Could anyone help with this? Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

I've upload my tex to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0a4uvnMj). In addition, my class file is [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?lc=1033&mkt=en-US#cid=13472D04377FFF19&id=13472D04377FFF19!105).

Comment: Please provide a simple, complete document illustrating the problem.

Comment: Did you do `\verb$...$`?

Comment: @percusse this doesn't produce errors: `\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {\verb$aaaa$};
\end{tikzpicture}`. Why do you suspect `\verb$...$`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, I've uploaded my tex file and my customized class as well.

Comment: @zhangway Please see if the answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165929/3954 helps you. If so, let us know, so we can close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, it works for me. You saved my day. Thanks a lot.