# tikz Error some package has redefined the meaning of the math-mode dollar sign

Tags: tikz-pgf, calc

I am using Tikz code from [package-lineno-not-working-well-skips-line-texlive-2016](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351984/package-lineno-not-working-well-skips-line-texlive-2016) and everything have been working very well.

When I added some `verbatim` text at the end, now I get this error from `lualtex`

```
Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\textgreater '
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `T1-default'.


! Package tikz Error: Sorry, some package has redefined the meaning of the math
-mode dollar sign. This is incompatible with tikz and its calc library and migh
t cause unrecoverable errors.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

I spend alot of time trying to make MWE. But it seems to be random. If I make the code smaller, or move `verbatim` to top of file, the error goes away. If I remove `geometry` package, error goes away. I even removed one blank line in random location, and error went away.

I looked at  [package-tikz-error-when-writing-some-text-in-verbatim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175476/package-tikz-error-when-writing-some-text-in-verbatim) and followed link to [semiverbatim-with-tikz-in-beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165929/semiverbatim-with-tikz-in-beamer) and tried the fix given there but that did not remove the error:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So I am not sure what to do now. I'd like to keep the tikz code, which shows the line numbers. But I also want to add `verbatim`.  The smallest Latex file I can show is 150 lines long. This causes the error. I can post a link to the file, since it is long? Or I can paste here also? Will do in few minutes...

I am using TexLive 2016, on Linux mint. On windows, using Miktex 9. Both give same error.

**End of log file is:**

```
 Package tikz Error: Sorry, some package has redefined the meaning of the math
-mode dollar sign. This is incompatible with tikz and its calc library and migh
t cause unrecoverable errors.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.26 \end{verbatim}

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 12117 strings out of 494611
 100000,319454 words of node,token memory allocated 2441 words of node memory still in use:
   15 hlist, 1 vlist, 3 rule, 4 local_par, 4 dir, 101 glue, 8 kern, 44 penalty, 
150 glyph, 25 attribute, 48 glue_spec, 25 attribute_list, 4 temp, 4 if_stack, 1 
write, 5 pdf_literal, 3 pdf_colorstack nodes
   avail lists: 2:6,3:1,4:1,8:1,9:1
 15679 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 17 fonts using 981063 bytes
 55i,3n,54p,401b,458s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,90000000b,100000s

warning  (pdf backend): no pages of output.

PDF statistics: 3 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

### Listing

Thanks to TorbjørnT help in chat, he was able to make even smaller MWE that shows the error. Here it is

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}%
\usepackage[margin=1.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,everypage}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AddEverypageHook{%
    \small
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]      
      \path (current page.north west) --  (current page.south west) 
            \foreach \i in {1,...,\fakelinenos} 
               { node [pos={(\i-.5)/\fakelinenos}, 
                  xshift=\fakelinenoshift, line number style] {\i} }  ;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}

\tikzset{%
  line numbers/.store in=\fakelinenos,
  line numbers=72,
  line number shift/.store in=\fakelinenoshift,
  line number shift=5mm,
  line number style/.style={text=gray},
}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{20cm}
\begin{verbatim}
data1 = makeTable[0.01, 0, 2, 0];
At one second, using h=0.01 speed is 16.078 at step n = 100
At 2 seconds, using h=0.01 speed is 19.206 at step n = 200
data2 = makeTable[0.005, 0, 2, 0];
At one second, using h=0.005 speed is 16.02 at step n = 200
At 2 seconds, using h=0.005 speed is 19.195 at step n = 400
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you should be able to post a MWE the document is only 171 lines and  you can shrink by replacing each equation by `1=2` and each (say) 5 line paragraph by `a\\a\\a\\a\\a`  But I would guess you have tikz in the page head at the point verbatim is breaking over a page.

Comment: The problem is obviously that LaTeX is trying to make the picture when it is in the middle of a `verbatim` environment. What should `\fakelinenos` and `\fakelinenoshift` mean?

Comment: Perhaps I removed too much, the `\tikzset` where `\fakelinenos` and `\fakelinenoshift` is defined might be good to have, even if the error itself is reproduced without it.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. ok, I added `\tikzset` back. I saw you removed it, but  I assumed you did not think it was needed. It is back into the code now. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the chat you said you are using lualatex. In this case you can reset the catcode table:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}%
\usepackage[margin=1.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,everypage}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AddEverypageHook{%
    \small    
    \catcodetable  \catcodetable@latex    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \path (current page.north west) --  (current page.south west)
            \foreach \i in {1,...,\fakelinenos}
               { node [pos={(\i-.5)/\fakelinenos},
                  xshift=\fakelinenoshift, line number style] {\i} }  ;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}
\makeatother    
\tikzset{%
  line numbers/.store in=\fakelinenos,
  line numbers=72,
  line number shift/.store in=\fakelinenoshift,
  line number shift=5mm,
  line number style/.style={text=gray},
}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{20cm}
\begin{verbatim}
data1 = makeTable[0.01, 0, 2, 0];
At one second, using h=0.01 speed is 16.078 at step n = 100
At 2 seconds, using h=0.01 speed is 19.206 at step n = 200
data2 = makeTable[0.005, 0, 2, 0];
At one second, using h=0.005 speed is 16.02 at step n = 200
At 2 seconds, using h=0.005 speed is 19.195 at step n = 400 
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just avoid running the tikz inside verbatim, also I copied your required tikz setup from the previous question.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}%
\usepackage[margin=1.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,everypage}
\newsavebox\mybox
\tikzset{%
  line numbers/.store in=\fakelinenos,
  line numbers=45,
  line number shift/.store in=\fakelinenoshift,
  line number shift=0mm,
  line number style/.style={text=gray},
}
\savebox\mybox{\small
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \path (current page.north west) --  (current page.south west) 
            \foreach \i in {1,...,\fakelinenos} 
               { node [pos={(\i-.5)/\fakelinenos}, 
                  xshift=\fakelinenoshift, line number style] {\i} }  ;
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\AtBeginDocument{\AddEverypageHook{%
  \llap{\smash{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\textheight-80pt}{\usebox{\mybox}}}}}}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{20cm}
\begin{verbatim}
data1 = makeTable[0.01, 0, 2, 0];
At one second, using h=0.01 speed is 16.078 at step n = 100
At 2 seconds, using h=0.01 speed is 19.206 at step n = 200
data2 = makeTable[0.005, 0, 2, 0];
At one second, using h=0.005 speed is 16.02 at step n = 200
At 2 seconds, using h=0.005 speed is 19.195 at step n = 400
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you avoid to run the tikz inside verbatim? I don't get with your answer.

Comment: @antoine the tikz is run at the start of the document in a box and the box just copied each page, rather than executing the tikz each page

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I had a verbatim block that spanned pages, and I had a tikz function within the document's footer. So the tikz code was effectively being run within the verbatim section, as the footer was being rendered at the point of a new page being started during the verbatim block.

Comment: I'm posting this answer as this question is the first hit in Google for the error being received, and this was the problem in my case.