# tikz Error some package has redefined the meaning of the math-mode dollar sign, which documentation?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am going back to some old TeX code (huge project) and running into major bitrot. I am for the moment getting this error message:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, some package has redefined the meaning of the math
-mode dollar sign. This is incompatible with tikz and its calc library and migh
t cause unrecoverable errors.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
```

I am trying to find the explanation promised but can't find anything when searching for that error message in the: 
https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf

Am I looking at the wrong place?

Comment: An explanation of this problem is described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165937/).

Comment: That documentation is quite old (current version is 3.0.1a), better to look at CTAN to get the latest one, or open a terminal/command prompt on your system, type `texdoc tikz` and hit enter. I can't see that it is explained there though. At least not the error.

Comment: Such error message may happen because of using `preview` package. [Some info](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/536029/222496). I worked problem around by using `\documentclass[preview]{standalone}` instead of _preview_ package.