# Multi-page verbatim env changes catcode in footer

Tags: latex-base

If a LaTeX2e environment `verbatim` spreads two pages, then in the footer of first page, catcode of symbols like `$` and `_` are changed to 12 (other), as if the whole footer is inside the `verbatim` env.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@oddfoot{footer: \showcatcode{\$}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\showcatcode[1]{%
  catcode of symbol #1\space is \the\catcode`#1\hfill
}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{.9\textheight}
main body: \showcatcode{\$}
\begin{verbatim}
0
1
2
3
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of mwe]

In most cases, this won't cause any problems since the contents of footer is rather simple. But if footer contains something like `tikzpicture`, the error raises (see questions like [tikz Error some package has redefined the meaning of the math-mode dollar sign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/352297/79060) and [semiverbatim with tikz in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165929/79060)).

The same problem exists when using verbatim-like environments in packages `verbatim` and `fancyhdr`, but not `listings`. Guess `listings` uses another mechanism.

My question is:

1. Since the problem is reproducible in LaTeX2e, can we treat it as a bug?
2. If it is a bug, how can we fix it, and fix it in the most general case?
   Since in the linked questions there have been solutions like 1) restore catcode by luatex only command `\catcodetable@latex`, and 2) save contents of footer in box.

---

A supplement question:

If I set `\def\@oddfoot{footer: \showcatcode{\$} $a$ \showcatcode{\$}}` in the above example, the output shows that the catcode of `$` is always 12, but `$a$` still acts like the catcode of `$` is 3. How can this happen? (it seems the footer is treated differently than main body in output routine)

Comment: Also you should only ask one question at a time. But the effect you observe is that the catcodes are [frozen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498716/what-does-frozen-mean-e-g-for-catcodes) when you set the footer. The TikZ problem ony appears because TikZ "unfreezes" the catcodes again.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger The supplement question shows that even if "catcode of $ is 12", the dollar symbol can still serve as math shift. Since the supplement question part, I am currently not sure if this is a tikz issue, a verbatim pkg issue, or a latex-base issue. I will make a new question relating the supplement question only.